# Which controls to use for a Mac OS X application?

Tags: macos, cocoa, controls

I developed some app for iPhone/iPad, so I know the basic concepts of Cocoa programming. Now I need to write a Mac OS X application. If you help me to choose the right controls to use, I'll study the Apple documentation reference for them.

I need:

- a control to show a grid of thumbnails (png images); I'll be able to change the order of the thumbnails by dragging and dropping them;
- a control to show a single image (e.g. UIImageView of Cocoa Touch) with the possibility to drag and drop another image over the first one; besides I need to move and resize the second image by dragging its corners (as if corners were "anchors");
- a control to browse the media files on the Mac (possibly iPhoto images, iTunes DRM-free songs, or simply the content of a given folder), like the media browser of iMovie.

I use Xcode 4.2.

Comment: The minimum targeted OS version would be more useful information than the Xcode version. :-) New Cocoa APIs don't come with Xcode versions, they come with OS versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use `NSCollectionView` and co. for this. Xcode has a sample application somewhere in documentation (browsing various images) as well as tutorial on how to setup `NSCollectionView` yourself.
2. Check `NSImageView`. You can basically find any Cocoa control alternative to Cocoa Touch just by changing `UI` prefix to `NS`.
3. There is no such control per-se (unless `IKImageBrowser` for backgrounds), but using aforementioned `NSCollectionView` and some API for media files you should get around pretty quickly.

Also check `ImageKit` framework for images (for browsing, viewing and modifying).

Comment: For #3, AV Foundation has AVAssetsLibrary on iOS, but not on the Mac. Karelia Software has a third-party iMedia Browser framework that can do the job. https://github.com/karelia/imedia